# Runtime restart application in visual studio debug mode

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I use the following code to restart my console application:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
Environment.Exit(0);
```

This works just fine when I start it directly from its built executable. But if i debug it using Visual Studio, it won't. This is because Visual Studio runs `application.vhost.exe` first, which starts my application then. Now if I just run this `vhost.exe`, it won't run my application. I assume I have to pass command line arguments first.

My questions are the following:

1. How can I make sure my program will restart itself also while it's debugged within Visual Studio?
2. I thought about using the `#if(DEBUG)` preprocessor directive to pass the `.vhost.exe`-file arguments only when the software is debugged, but which arguments do I need to pass him to make it work properly? Also, this seems to me kind of "dirty" - Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In project properties, disable "Visual Studio Hosting Process". Then no "*.vshost.exe" will be used.
2) If you call [System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx), the debugger selection dialog will be shown and you can select already running instance of visual studio.